# mysql innerjoin and union

Tags: mysql, database, crystal-reports

I previously ask on how to join multiple tables thru MYSQL but now I encountered a new issue.

Say I have these several tables.

Reimbursement Table

```
-Name---Check Number-----Date------Reimbursement--
-John-----1--------------7/23/12-------$100-------
-Joe------2--------------7/23/12-------$102-------
-Jane-----3--------------7/23/12-------$103-------
-Jill-----4--------------7/23/12-------$104-------
```

Original Claim

```
-Name---Check Number-----Date---------Amount--
-John-----1--------------7/23/12-------$100---
-Joe------2--------------7/23/12-------$102---
-Jane-----3--------------7/23/12-------$103---
-Jill-----4--------------7/23/12-------$100---
```

Adjusted Claim

```
-Name---Check Number-----Date---------Amount--
-Jill-----4--------------7/23/12-------$4-----
```

End Result through crystal report should be

```
-Name---Check #---Claim Type----Date Paid----Amount----Reimbursement--
-John-----1-------Original--------7/23/12-----$100-------$100---------
-Joe------2-------Original--------7/23/12-----$102-------$102---------
-Jane-----3-------Original--------7/23/12-----$103-------$103---------
-Jill-----4-------Original-------7/23/12------$100-------$104---------
-Jill-----4-------Adjusted-------7/23/12------$4----------------------
```

not

```
-Name---Check #---Claim Type----Date Paid----Amount----Reimbursement--
-John-----1-------Original--------7/23/12-----$100-------$100---------
-Joe------2-------Original--------7/23/12-----$102-------$102---------
-Jane-----3-------Original--------7/23/12-----$103-------$103---------
-Jill-----4-------Original-------7/23/12------$100-------$104---------
-Jill-----4-------Adjusted-------7/23/12------$4---------$104---------
```

my current script is:

```
Select  mt.`Check Number` as `Check Number`,
        mt.`Payment Date` as `Payment Date`,
        mt.`Payment Type` as `Payment Type`,
        c1.`Facility Name` as `Facility Name`,
        'Adjustment June 2012' as `Claim Type`,
        c1.`Amount` as Amount,
        mt.Reimbursement as Reimbursement 
  From  Reimbursement mt 
               Inner Join ClaimAdjust_6_2012 c1 
                  on c1.`Check Number`  = mt.`Check Number` and 
                     mt.`Payment Date` = c1.`Payment Date` 
  Where mt.`Payment Date`>='2012-7-1' And 
        mt.`Payment Date`<'2012-8-1' 

Union 

Select  mt.`Check Number` as `Check Number`,
        mt.`Payment Date` as `Payment Date`,
        mt.`Payment Type` as `Payment Type`,
        c1.`Facility Name` as `Facility Name`,
        'Original June 2012' as `Claim Type`,
        c1.`Amount` as Amount,
        mt.Reimbursement as Reimbursement 
 From   Reimbursement mt 
              Inner Join Claim_6_2012 c1 
                    on c1.`Check Number`  = mt.`Check Number` and 
                        mt.`Payment Date` = c1.`Payment Date` 
Where   mt.`Payment Date`>='2012-7-1' And 
        mt.`Payment Date`<'2012-8-1'
```

Comment: How I can create the end result on crystal report without having the reimbursement coming out twice for the same check number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this query work? Why don't you only JOIN the `Reimbursement Table` and `Original Claim` and UNION it with `Adjusted Claim`

```
SELECT      a.Name, a.CheckNumber, a.`Date`,
            b.Amount, a.Reimbursement
FROM        Reimbursement a INNER JOIN
                OrginalClaim b ON
                    a.Name = b.Name AND
                    a.CheckNmber = b.CheckNumber AND
                    a.`Date` = b.`Date`
UNION
SELECT      Name, CheckNumber, `Date`, Amount, NULL as Reimbursement
FROM        AdjustedClaim
```

Comment: There will be times that the reimbursement is needed on the AdjustedClaim.

Comment: Part of your script help me complete my goal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is pretty simple.  Just ignore the reimbursement in the first subquery:

```
Select mt.`Check Number` as `Check Number`,mt.`Payment Date` as `Payment Date`,mt.`Payment Type` as `Payment Type`,c1.`Facility Name` as `Facility Name`,'Adjustment June 2012' as `Claim Type`,c1.`Amount` as Amount, NULL as Reimbursement
From Reimbursement mt  Inner Join
     ClaimAdjust_6_2012 c1
    on c1.`Check Number` = mt.`Check Number` and mt.`Payment Date` = c1.`Payment Date`
Where mt.`Payment Date`>='2012-7-1' And mt.`Payment Date`<'2012-8-1' 
Union all
Select mt.`Check Number` as `Check Number`,mt.`Payment Date` as `Payment Date`,mt.`Payment Type` as `Payment Type`,c1.`Facility Name` as `Facility Name`,'Original June 2012' as `Claim Type`,c1.`Amount` as Amount,mt.Reimbursement as Reimbursement
From Reimbursement mt Inner Join
     Claim_6_2012 c1
     on c1.`Check Number` = mt.`Check Number` and mt.`Payment Date` = c1.`Payment Date`
Where mt.`Payment Date`>='2012-7-1' And mt.`Payment Date`<'2012-8-1'
```

This joins in the table, so you can still use the payment dates, but sets the value to NULL.

Comment: I cannot leave AdjustedClaim with the Null value for reimbursement, The only time it should be null is when the AdjustedClaim and OriginalClaim share the same `Check Number` and `Payment Date` if it does not then it should have its own relation to the Reimbursement

Comment: This query was based on your original data.  Can you provide an example in the question to clarify what you really need?